# SQL Query to find the most frequent element in relation to an other element in a table

Tags: sql

I have a hospital database which contains the tables:

`equipment`

`id                CHAR(40) NOT NULL, 
     model             CHAR(20) NOT NULL, 
     serialno          VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL, 
     release_date      DATE, 
     PRIMARY KEY (id)`

and

```
appointmentrelations
appointment_id CHAR(40) NOT NULL, 
 medicine_id    CHAR(40) NOT NULL, 
 equipment_id   CHAR(40) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (appointment_id, medicine_id, equipment_id), 
 FOREIGN KEY (appointment_id) REFERENCES appointment(id), 
 FOREIGN KEY (medicine_id)REFERENCES medicineprice(medicine_id), 
 FOREIGN KEY (equipment_id) REFERENCES equipment(id)
```

and other some other tables.

Table appointmetrelations describes the appointments of the hospital and relates an appoointment with the equipments and the medicines that where used in it.

I want to write a query which find the equipment which was used the most in relation to his age.

```
appointmentrelations
a1    m1    e1  
a2    m2    e2
a3    m3    e3
a4    m3    e3
a5    m4    e2

equipment
e1  model1  se1 2004-07-14
e2  model2  se2 2017-10-19
e3  model3  se3 2015-01-08
```

In the above sample the equipment that were used the most in relation to his age is e2.

I tried the following:

```
SELECT equipment_id, COUNT(DISTINCT appointment_id) AS ab
FROM appointmentrelations
GROUP BY equipment_id
ORDER BY ab DESC
LIMIT 1
```

to count the number of different appointments that each equipment were used in but I dont know how to relate it with the equipment age.

Comment: update you question add  a proper data samplke and the expected  result  .

Comment: Thanks for the advice.. I did it.

Comment: Can you please post the expected output for this sample data ?

Comment: @S.John, 'In the above sample the equipment that were used the most in relation to his age is e2.'  How do you come to this conclusion? Please explain further.

Comment: Because e2 has realease year 2017 so its younger when e3 has realease year 2015 so its older.

Answer (score 1):

If i understand correctly, you can wrap your current query in `subquery`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM equipment e
WHERE id  = (SELECT equipment_id
             FROM appointmentrelations
             GROUP BY equipment_id
             ORDER BY COUNT(DISTINCT appointment_id) DESC
             LIMIT 1);
```

Comment: @parladneupane... Thanks.

Comment: Also adding `now() - e.release_date  as age` in query would give age, i think he is looking for age.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but this just gives the equipment which was used the most. I want to relate this result to each equipment age.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an inner join for obtain all the result order by usage

```
  select e.id, count(DISTINCT a.appointment_id), e.model, e.date 
  from equipment e 
  inner join appointmentrelations a on a.appointment_id = e.id
  group by e.id , e.model, e.date 
  order by count(DISTINCT a.appointment_id) DESC
```